# How to compile current document instead of root in TeXstudio?

Tags: texstudio

In Options->Root Document, TeXstudio allows the user to automatically detect the root document or manually set the root document. Then F5 will build & view from that root file. This is a pretty nice feature.

However, I want to be able to build & view the current file. This is how most other editors work but I have not been able to do it with TeXstudio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an open [feature request](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/872/).

As a workaround, you can set the root of the subfiles to themselves. I.e. if you have `mysubfile.tex`, you can add the following entry to its top:

```
% !TeX root = mysubfile
```

Comment: Just in case anybody else forgot just like me, make sure "Detect Automatically" is active in Options->Root Document for this to work.

Comment: But everytime you open a document in texstudio while a Master file is already opened, it gets linked automatically to the master file and the header is ignored. You need to reset "Detect Automatically" via mouse/menu actions, which is irritating.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you import those sub-documents with `\input` or `\include` with the preamble in the master document only, those separate files will not compile on their own. There are two possible solutions:

1. Quick, one-time. Create a copy of the master file and remove all sub-documents that you do not need (or comment those inclusion lines). Compile. Voilà!
2. If you really need to be able to compile separate sub-documents (article collection is a possible case), have a look at the [standalone](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) package. It allows you to compile both the master document and the separate input files as if they had been separate projects, with their preambles (if you choose the option shown below or not). Just use the class you want (say, `article`) for your root document with the corresponding package.

Use this in your master file (the sooner you include the `standalone` package, the better, according to its documentation):

```
\documentclass{article} % Root document
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
```

The last line is needed to correctly treat chapter-specific preambles. Then, for each chapter (or whatever division you use for the parts of your document), use

```
\documentclass[crop=false]{standalone} % Sub-document
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
```

This will allow you to compile both the master document and the subdocuments.

If you are not familiar with it, please try the example from [this wonderful article](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Multi-file_LaTeX_projects#The_standalone_package) (in the example, the extension of the subfiles is assumed to be `.tex`, so you can create them as an example and then copy the text and the preambles from your files to see whether it works).

Comment: I had compatibility issues with the standalone package, so I hacked together an alternative solution with a universal preamble file (including \documentclass) that checks whether it has already been run and responds accordingly. All my files run on their own, but TeXstudio only wants to run the (biggest, slowest) master file.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the solution by faltfe in: [In TeXstudio, how to compile only the subfile?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450546/in-texstudio-how-to-compile-only-the-subfile)

You can use the following macro to compile the current document and display it in the embedded pdf viewer:

```
%SCRIPT

function quote(filename){
    return '"' + filename + '"';
}

var filename = app.getCurrentFileName();
var dir = filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf("/"));
var pdflatexcmd = '../MikTex/texmfs/install/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe  -src -interaction=nonstopmode '
var proc = system(pdflatexcmd + quote(filename), dir);
proc.waitForFinished();

var pdfFilename = quote(filename.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, ".pdf"));

app.runInternalCommand("txs:///view-pdf-internal" , "--embedded", pdfFilename);
```

You can register a keyboard shortcut for this macro, eg: <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>F1</kbd> .

This allows you to compile and view the current selected document by just running this macro.

(For more info on defining / running macros, see: http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33)